# Which CMS to interface with magento

Tags: magento, e-commerce, typo3

I will made a website with two types of contents :

- a catalog with about 500 000 products (books only) ; I'll need to interface with an external database for daily updates
- many pages contents in a structural menu with a lot of categories and subcategories, with links between them and sometimes, an inside view of a magento product.

I've made a lot of website withTypo3 and some with Magento.

My first idea was to try Typogento but it seems not really used ; what do you think about it ?
Otherwise, what would you advise me ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a test install of Typogento and try it out. Though it's not very wide-spread, Typogento works fine. You can use the current TYPO3 release and recent Magento versions (at least Magento 1.4.1.).

It's a bit of an hassle until you modified everything to your needs, but then you can do exactly what you described above (e.g. insert products on regular pages). Also, both backends stay available seperately, so you can maintain your product catalogue in the Magento backend.

There are several case studies available in the [Typogento forum](http://www.typogento.com/forum/tgb/topics/success_stories.html), for example:
http://www.found4you.de/ Most of them german I am afraid :(

I am curious about any other solution posted here.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal Commerce looks very close to these objectives. You could use taxonomies to manage all types of categories You need.

http://www.drupalcommerce.org/
http://demo.commerceguys.com/dc/catalog/wearables
http://www.drupalcommerce.org/administration

Regards.

Comment: Looks promising. Do you have (positive) experience with it?

Comment: I've good experience with Drupal & Magento. What I could confirm at the moment : the structure of the code of Drupal Commerce is very near to Magento, it's quite clear & functional.